# Does constant $C_1$ and $C_2$ must be rational? ODE equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to solve a ODE question has following:

> The solution $\phi(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t),w(t))$ from equation system:
>   $$x'= y,\quad y'=-x,\quad z'=w,\quad w'=-k^2z $$
>   That satisfied the initial condition $\phi(0)=(1,0,0,1)$ is periodic. The correct answer could be:

A) $k$ is the integer number

B) $k=0$

C) $k>0$

**D) $k$ is the rational number and different of zero** (CORRECT)

E) $k$ is not the rational number

*My attempt:*

Since: $z''+k^2z = 0\Rightarrow m = e^{(a\pm bj)t}\Rightarrow m^2 + k^2=0\Rightarrow m = \pm j|k|$

$z(t) = e^{0\cdot t}(C_1\cdot \cos|k|t+C_2\cdot \sin|k|t)$

and

$w(t) = -C_1\cdot |k|\sin|k|t+C_2\cdot |k| \cos|k|t$

So, $z(0) =0, w(0) = 1\quad \therefore\quad C_1 = 0, C_2 = \dfrac{1}{|k|}$

$$z(t) = \dfrac{1}{|k|}\cdot \sin|k|t,\quad w(t) = \cos|k|t$$

Ok. despite the answer says that the $k$ is a rational number and different of zero, I'd like to know why the constant $k$ must be a rational number?

I know that if the $\phi(t)$ is periodic there is a rational relation between angular frequencies those signals but the angular frequencies of $z$ and $w$ is the same. So $|k|$ for example could be $\sqrt{3}$.

I cant conclude that only if I assume que $C_2$ is a rational number.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: $x, y$ are also periodic with the same period as $z, w$.

Comment: I didnt. I thought I wouldn't need

Comment: So put $k=\sqrt{3}$ in and see that the 4-dimensional solution is not periodic.  Each coordinate separately is periodic.